# Azure App Service Autehntication (EasyAuth) validation

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service, azure-appservice, azure-authentication

I am configuring an Azure app service to use the built in Authentication (EasyAuth) it seems to be working well with no auth code written at all. I am able to get the id and access tokens from the headers as expected.

What I am wondering now is what type of validation I should be doing on those tokens within the app to be sure they are legit. I understand the auth layer placed infront the of the app takes care of this, but I am concerned that if that auth is ever mistakenly disabled the app will be wide open.

It appears I might be able to POST the id_token from the x-ms-token-aad-id-token header to https://{sitename}/.auth/login/aad and this will validate that the token is legit? Is this a good and simple way to double check auth was done properly?

Answer (score 0):

You may use the below link to understand the details.

[Tutorial: Authenticate users E2E - Azure App Service | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/tutorial-auth-aad?pivots=platform-linux#configure-auth)